# Is there a way to improve sound quality in Linux?

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, pulse-audio, audacity

Total noob here, I did do some research before posting this question here, been using Linux since long and not satisfied by the audio quality that the Windows Counterpart provides (proprietary Dolby Processing etc.)

There is an answer that seems will work at the end of this post :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27122564/which-version-of-linux-has-support-for-dolby-advanced-audio-v2/5368816

But I couldn't understand the part where its said that "Record a -0 dBFS impulse tone".

Can anyone provide an extremely noob friendly answer?

Comment: Sonia, Tim was last seen here approx. 12 hours ago, he still helps people here. @Tim could you answer this question?